# NativeScript-Vue Webpack Can't resolve 'styles/style-one' on setup

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm new to NativeScript and I'm trying to create a new app using vue, following the instructions here: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/

NOTE: I'm using `vue-cli v3`, so instead of `vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template <project-name>`, I had to use `vue create <project-name>` then `vue add vue-cli-plugin-nativescript-vue`.

I am getting the following error when doing `tns preview` on my android device:

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to create a simple mobile app, and I'm getting an error on the setup phase. Thank you!

Specs:

- `node v10.20.1`
- `vue-cli v3.11.0`
- `tns v6.5.0`

Comment: This occurs without any changes in newly created project? What you have in `App.vue`?

Comment: @Manoj Reading a bit more in this article for the `vue-cli-plugin-nativescript-vue` plugin:
https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-plugin-nativescript-vue

Renaming my CSS files from `style-one.css` to `style-one.native.css` for mobile did the trick. I'm able to successfully run the app in my phone now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a bit more in this article for the `vue-cli-plugin-nativescript-vue` plugin:
https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-plugin-nativescript-vue

Renaming my CSS files from `style-one.css` to `style-one.native.css` for mobile did the trick. I'm able to successfully run the app in my phone now.